# Is this trigger efficient? Subscribing owner and teamMembers

Tags: trigger, entitysubscription

Trying to make the Opportunity Owner and Team Members follow the Opportunity - I think this is working but I bet there is a more compactway to process. Thanks!

```
  trigger OppOwnerFollower on Opportunity (after insert, after update) {

  List <EntitySubscription> Esses = new List <EntitySubscription>();
  List <id> Opps = new List <id>();
  List <EntitySubscription> EssesTeam = new List <EntitySubscription>();  

for(Opportunity opp: System.Trigger.new){

    Esses.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentId=opp.id, SubscriberId=Opp.OwnerId));
    Opps.add(opp.id);
}    

List <OpportunityTeamMember> OPTMS = [select ID, OpportunityId, Userid from OpportunityTeamMember where OpportunityId IN: opps];

    for (OpportunityTeamMember OOO: OPTMS)    {
        Esses.add(New EntitySubscription(ParentId=OOO.OpportunityId, SubscriberId=OOO.UserId));

    }


    database.insert(Esses,false);


}
```

Comment: Should be a trigger on `OpportunityTeamMember` I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you have the right idea, there are maybe some small quality of life changes you could make to what you currently have:

```
for (OpportunityTeamMember OOO: [select ID, OpportunityId, Userid from OpportunityTeamMember where OpportunityId IN: opps]){
```

You could consider other ways to populate Opps but since you are iterating the Trigger.new list it is fine.

Aside from that if you really wanted to make this better you could switch to using [a trigger framework or logic-less trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices).

The one thing I would point out - what is happening if the Opp Owner or Team changes? It looks like the old members will stay subscribers.

Comment: thanks. I realize follows could accumulate and changes would leave people on but I think for now that's acceptable. Trigger framework - when I have time to clean up this inherited code base!

Comment: `WHERE OpportunityId IN :Trigger.new`